# API via PowerShell with upload file

Tags: ajax, powershell

I'm trying to Upload apk file to our cloud via API.

When I'm test it on POSTMAN everything works fine,
but when I'm trying to convert it to PowerShell, it's not working at all.

Here is the relevant parameters on AJAX:

```js
var form = new FormData();
form.append("app-data", "Netflix_v6.7.1_build_28752_apkpure.com.apk");
form.append("newVersion", "true");
form.append("Partver", "22222");
form.append("platformType", "ANDROID");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://URL",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic CodeHere",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "b581369a-98sas-a49d-231e-sddsadsadsaf2"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

My code:

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("authorization", "Basic CodeHere")
$headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache")
$headers.Add("postman-token", "b581369a-98sas-a49d-231e-sddsadsadsaf2")

$ori = "app-data"
$url = "https://URL"
$person = @{
    "app-data"    = "\\server\Netflix_v6.7.1_build_28752_apkpure.com.apk"
    newVersion    = 'true'
    cmPartitionId = '22222'
    platformType  = 'ANDROID'
}
$body = (ConvertTo-Json $person)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: So, what doesn't work about that code? Are you getting an error? What is the response?

Comment: I'm getting error 500.. but i need that App-data will contain my apk .. when i do it on postman on app-data parameter i choose to browse and select file

Comment: Error 500 means the server didn't like something about your request. Try passing the file via `-InFile "Netflix_v6.7.1_build_28752_apkpure.com.apk"` rather than a body parameter. Also `\\server\file` is not a valid UNC path. It must be `\\server\share\file` or `\\server\share\sub\folder\file`. If that doesn't help you need to inspect the requests with something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: The cmdlet cannot run because the following conflicting parameters are specified: Body and InFile. Specify either Body or Infile, then retry.